# Power BI Embedded from PHP. Obtain an Azure Authentication token OAuth

Tags: php, azure, oauth, powerbi

I'm trying to utilise Power BI Embedded from a PHP based website to embed a non-public Power BI document into a web page (behind a user login).

There is a C# version here that I have got running: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/power-bi-embedded-integrate-report-into-web-app/. I effectively need to replicate this in PHP).

(also see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/power-bi-embedded-get-started/)

I'm stuck trying to obtain a auth-token.

The C# site generates an auth-token that if I paste into my PHP site, I can use to load the Power BI sheet. However, I'm not sure how to generate this from PHP - presumably a curl request somewhere, but I can't work out what I need to send where? [Edit: I've been sniffing packets and it doesn't seem to make an http request to generate this, so perhaps I just need to know how to generate it myself?]. The C# is using a built in library (PowerBIToken) to do this.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Report(string reportId)
    {


        var devToken = PowerBIToken.CreateDevToken(this.workspaceCollection, this.workspaceId);
        using (var client = this.CreatePowerBIClient(devToken))
        {
            var reportsResponse = await client.Reports.GetReportsAsync(this.workspaceCollection, this.workspaceId);
            var report = reportsResponse.Value.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Id == reportId);
            var embedToken = PowerBIToken.CreateReportEmbedToken(this.workspaceCollection, this.workspaceId, report.Id);

            var viewModel = new ReportViewModel
            {
                Report = report,
                AccessToken = embedToken.Generate(this.accessKey)
            };

            return View(viewModel);
        }
    }
```

I'm looking for a simple solution where I can walk through each step rather than a bloated library if possible.

Comment: Do you want to call the Power BI Embedded API at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt712303.aspx from PHP, or you want to integrate Power BI reports into your PHP web?

Comment: @Gary Liu potentially both. The API you linked to requires an app token, and that's the bit I can't figure out how to generate from PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some investigation I worked this one out myself.

The token is a JWT token, which can be generated directly from PHP.

Include the JWT php class from here: https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt

To authenticate for calls to the API use:

```
$key = "<your Azure access key>";
$payload = array(
    "ver" => "0.1.0",
    "type" => "dev",
    "wcn" => "<your workspace collection name>",
    "wid" => "<your workspace ID>",
    "iss" => "PowerBISDK",
    "aud" => "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api",
    "exp" => time()+60*60,
    "nbf" => time()
);
$token = JWT::encode($payload,$key);
```

And to authenticate for displaying a report in the browser use:

```
$key = "<your Azure access key>";
$payload = array(
    "ver" => "0.1.0",
    "type" => "embed",
    "wcn" => "<your workspace collection name>",
    "wid" => "<your workspace ID>",
    "rid" => "<your reportID (as uploaded to your collection)>",
    "iss" => "PowerBISDK",
    "aud" => "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api",
    "exp" => time()+60*60,
    "nbf" => time()
);
$token = JWT::encode($payload,$key);
```

You can then use this as the `powerbi-access-token` attribute on your report div in the browser.

Also, in case it helps anyone, here's an example of the Curl I use for the API:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.powerbi.com/beta/collections/<your workspace collection name>/workspaces/<your workspace ID>/reports");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); //Might be required for https
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Authorization: AppToken " . $token
));
$response_json = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$response_data = json_decode($response,true);
```

Answer (score 2):

This doc page helped me getting token and embed codes by php/js - it describes every request and response step by step:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645542.aspx

**Authorization Code Grant Flow Diagram:**

- Register the Application in Azure AD
- Request an authorization code
- Use the Authorization Code to Request an Access Token
- Use the Access Token to Access the Resource
- Use the Refresh Token to Request a New Access Token

Answer (score 0):

The C# code snippet you provide seams to integrate Power BI reports into your web site.

As Power BI Supports for embed power BI dashboard on your website via IFrame.
[Embed the powerBi report in html iFrame](https://fromjami.wordpress.com/2016/03/25/how-to-embed-the-powerbi-report-in-html-iframe/).

So to implement this requirement in PHP web app, you can try to leverage [Power BI for HTML / JavaScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript).

Or directly create IFrame Dom attributed in your PHP view script. E.G.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // post the auth token to the iFrame.
        function postActionLoadReport() {

            // get the access token.
            accessToken = '<?php echo $accessToken;?>';

            // return if no a
            if ("" === accessToken)
                return;

            // construct the push message structure
            // this structure also supports setting the reportId, groupId, height, and width.
            // when using a report in a group, you must provide the groupId on the iFrame SRC
            var m = { action: "loadReport", accessToken: accessToken};
            message = JSON.stringify(m);

            // push the message.
            iframe = document.getElementById('iFrameEmbedReport');
            iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(message, "*");;
        }
     </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <p><b>Embedded Report</b></p>
        <table> <tr>
                    <td>
                        <iframe id="iFrameEmbedReport" src="<?php echo $reportURI;?>" onload="postActionLoadReport()" height="768px" width="1024px" frameborder="1" seamless></iframe>
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

Please refer to the solution of the thread on Power BI community at http://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/report-embed-problem/td-p/11490/highlight/true.

Comment: Hello Gary, thank you for the thorough reply. Am I right in thinking that this is only for reports that have been published to web using the "file" > "publish to web" option on the Power BI site? Unfortunately this means that the reports are public which unfortunately is not appropriate for my use case. https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-service-publish-to-web/#article-wrapper

Comment: To clarify, are you looking for the solution in PHP to implement the functionality shown at https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-integrate-a-power-bi-tile-or-report/?

Comment: Yes, I think so - thanks Gary, this could be what I need: https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-authenticate-a-web-app/ I'll take a look

Comment: having looked further, I'm not sure this is what I need. I've reworded the initial question to hopefully make things clearer.